# Will OpenGL ES perform better than CoreAnimation for animating a hundred layers?

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, core-animation

I have an object, which consists of a CATransformLayer with two CAKeyframeAnimated sublayers. With only 10 instances of this object added to the view's layer, the fps is really dropping to a ~ 10/15 fps. I don't know exactly how much but it's not looking good. This make only 20 animations. The position of the object is not keyframed.

I'm running this on an iPad Mini.

Is this aleady too much for an iPad Mini, or could I get better results using OpenGL ES ?

Comment: OpenGL will always be faster but what exactly are you animating and what do you mean by the object is not even moving? A redraw is still a redraw regardless of the x,y location if a transform is taking place.

Comment: @MarkM I meant that I was just adding objects at random positions on the layer, just to check that the sublayers animations were ok.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you are trying to animate I would immediately recommend using something like Cocos2d to accomplish this. You can do a lot with CALayers but performance will always be better using an OpenGL based framework such as Cocos2d especially with a fairly complex scene.

Comment: @MarkM I was more testing CoreAnimation to see how it performs with a large numbers of layers than actually having a problem in a real application. I guess CALayers are meant for UI animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using Cocos2d for a fairly complex scene. There are some great tutorials on the net. Ray has always had some great tuts on the subject and it's where I first learned cocos2d. It's not as complicated as it may seem. Plus, adding physics is a breeze due to the massive community support. (http://www.raywenderlich.com/28602/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-bouncing-balls)